# Is it correct to say " a physical equation" when I'm talking about "a physics equation"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

If I would describe "2x+3=0", that's an algebraic equation. Is it okay to describe "E=mc^2" by saying its a "physical equation"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "physical equation" seems to be widely used in the sense of "an equation of physics", as a Google search will show.
I don't find it listed in a dictionary as such. Searching Wikipedia, the term appears in a number of articles about physics.

There is a definition of "physical" that would support that use:
[American Heritage Dictionary "physical" (4)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=physical)

> 4. Of or relating to matter and energy or the sciences dealing with them, especially physics.

I think you are safe using it that way.

Comment: Can you link to an example of where this term is used in correct context? My own Google search found several examples of this, but they were invariably surrounded by very poor English, and apparently just mistakes.

Comment: @user34258 I have made a new post with a number of citations. I posted it separately because it is lengthy.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty That looks great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

(This is an addendum to my earlier answer in response to a request for citations supporting the use of the term "physical equation". I have set it as a new answer because it is lengthy and might make the original answer a bit unwieldy.)

[MIT.edu DA_unified.pdf](https://web.mit.edu/2.25/www/pdf/DA_unified.pdf)

> Science is concerned only with expressing a physical relationship between one quantity and a set of others, that is, with **“physical equations.”** Nature is  indifferent  to  the  arbitrary  choices  we  make  when  we  pick  base  units.

[Google Books "Dimensional Analysis Practical Guides... Jonathan Worstel"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dimensional_Analysis/EfXJAgAAQBAJ?gbpv=1&dq=%2522physical%20equation%2522&pg=PA40&printsec=frontcover)

> Therefore, when we write a **physical equation**, we are, in essence, writing an equation that balances physical quantities alpha[psi] with the use of an equality sign.

[Google Books "Manual of Physics William Peddle"](https://books.google.com/books?id=c2NHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=%252522It+affords+a+useful+check+on+the+accuracy+of+algebraical+work%252522&source=bl&ots=RyUsuL3tgY&sig=ACfU3U3qfBrzbUULdKfsfEhIV1o-RjvksQ&hl=en&sa=X)

> It affords a useful check on the accuracy of algebraical work; for the dimensions of all the terms in a **physical equation** must be the same.

[Dummies.com Quantum stuff](https://www.dummies.com/article/academics-the-arts/science/quantum-physics/how-to-add-time-dependence-and-get-a-physical-equation-for-three-dimensional-free-particle-problems-161400/)

> "At some point, your quantum physics instructor may want you to add time dependence and get a **physical equation** for a three-dimensional free particle problem."

I haven't figured out how to post a graphic from Ngram, but here is a link showing the predominance of the term "physical equation" over "physics equation" (Though in this century the latter term is gaining, it is still used less.)

[Ngram "physical equation, physics equation"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=physical+equation%2C+physics+equation&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cphysical%20equation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cphysics%20equation%3B%2Cc0t1#t1;,physical%20equation;,c0;.t1;,physics%20equation;,c0)

Answer (score 1):

The expression E=mc^2 is a *formula* "a relationship or rule expressed in symbols."

Unlike the equation 2x+3=0, you don't "solve" E=mc^2.  If you are being careful, you can distinguish formulae from equations.

The term "physical equation" has little use. "physics equation" is more common and you can use this, but it misses out on the useful distinction between equations and formulae.

Comment: If the expression has two terms connected by an equals sign, it is an equation. It can be restated (solved) for any of its three variables. Given values for any two of its variables, it can be solved for the value of the third. It is a formula, but it is nonetheless an equation.

Answer (score 0):

No, the term *a physical equation* is not used, simply use:

> **a physics equation**

Or:

> **a scientific equation**